# Ctrl+Enter does not work on suggested edits improve option

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, suggested-edits, keyboard-shortcuts

I often now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit edits on sites, where I have greater than 2K reputation and the edit UI is integrated into the page, since I have a trackpad and it's a pain to scroll to click a button. Much to my dismay, this does not work on sites where I have less than 2K rep and the edit interface has its own interface, and worse, when I am improving a suggested edit. Can this shortcut(for lack of better terms) be implemented on the standalone edit page and the review interface? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

You can now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit edits on the *non*-inline edit page, as well as on review pages.